# Ho to read/write a local file from a webapp?

Tags: unity, webapps

I'd like to have a config dialog, then I need to read/write a local file from a webapp? Please, How could I do that?

Thanks in advance!

---

For @terdon question:

I'd like to add an Action QuickList which open a Config Dialog for my webapp. Then you could config autostart, Mobile/Desktop view, Enable notifications... Just a config dialog.

What webapp? This: https://launchpad.net/unity-webapps-telegram

What language is it written in? I'd like to launch a python app created with Glade + Python as my Gufw app.

What system is it running on? Ubuntu 14.04

What have you tried? Nothing, I'm lost. The API hasn't anything about this. I'm just asking :)

Comment: You need to give a _lot_ more detail than that. What webapp? What language is it written in? What system is it running on? **What have you tried?**

Comment: Hi @terdon :) I updated the post for your answers. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the kindness of a developer, I can give some information to my questions.

I can't read / write a local file; I can only use [W3C supported content storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage) mechanisms or Web SQL or Indexed DB.

Best regards!